# CodeIgniter Library: Access to CodeIgniter Superobject causes PHP Error of Severity:Notice

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter library. When I access it from my controller a PHP Error of Severity:Notice is generated. However, the debugger shows that the super object exists in the library and is the CI super object.

Here is the library class:

```
    class Auth_lib {

    protected $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->$CI =& get_instance();
        $this->$CI->load->model('auth_model');
        $this->$CI->load->library('session');
    }

    /**
     * checks if the current user is logged into a session
     * @param 
     * @return boolean 
     */
     public function is_logged_in(){
        $result = $this->$CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And this is how the library is called from my controller:

```
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url_helper');
            $this->load->library('auth_lib');

            // test if user is logged in and authorised, if not redirect to login controller

            if($this->auth_lib->is_logged_in() != null){
                // check if is admin
                }
            } else {
                // not logged in, redirect to login controller
            }

        }
```

So, why I am getting this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined variable: CI
>   Filename: libraries/Auth_lib.php
>   Line Number: 20

Comment: Try `$this->CI` instead of `$this->$CI`

Comment: If you are dead-set on making it work with `$this->$CI =& get_instance();` then before using `$CI` you will have to declare `$CI = 'CI';`

Comment: Also you have an extra bracket after // check if is admin

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Sometimes it helps a lot if one looks over the code to spot a simple error. Thanks, if you post this as answer, I will accept it

Comment: Looks like I didn't see your comment in time and someone else stole the thunder, oh well. Anyways, my comment might be wrong. If you want to declare `$CI = 'CI';` then you would have to change your code to `$this->{$CI} =& get_instance();`. PHP is fun like that. It lets you call functions and variables dynamically but whoever has to go back and read your code would hate you lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `$this->CI` instead of `$this->$CI`.
2. `return isset($result)?TRUE:FALSE;` from library's `is_logged_in()` function.

   **libraries/Auth_lib.php**

   ```
   class Auth_lib {

     protected $CI;

     public function __construct()
     {
       $this->CI =& get_instance();
       $this->CI->load->model('auth_model');
       $this->CI->load->library('session');
     }

   /**
    * checks if the current user is logged into a session
    * @param 
    * @return boolean 
    */
      public function is_logged_in(){
        $result = $this->CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        return isset($result)?TRUE:FALSE;//make sure that you have set  session or not
      }
   }
   ```

   **Controller**

   ```
   public function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->load->helper('url_helper');
           $this->load->library('auth_lib');

           // test if user is logged in and authorised, if not redirect to login controller

           if($this->auth_lib->is_logged_in()){
               // check if is admin
               }
           else {
               // not logged in, redirect to login controller
           }

       }
   ```